# dosel/zalenium is executing the last created docker image instead of elgalu/selenium image

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid, zalenium

I have already pulled elgalu/selenium and dosel/zalenium using the the docker pull.

Used the following code to start the zalenium:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -d -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged dosel/zalenium start --maxTestSessions 1 --desiredContainers 9
```

Here the dosel/zalenium starts correctly but the problem I am facing is that there are multiple docker images created after the latest elgalu/selenium version so, what zalenium is doing here is executing for selecting  the last created image whereas it should run the elgalu/selenium image.

I need help in fixing elgalu/selenium image as the permanent image which the dosel/zalenium will select everytime

I tried adding --seleniumImageName elgalu/selenium: latest at the last but it didn't work